# How to accumulate changes without renaming variable?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of Strings, `errors`. I do some checks and if any fail, I append a message to `errors`. Something like this:

```
let errors = []
let errors' = errors ++ if (check1 fails) then ["check1 failed"] else []
let errors'' = errors' ++  if (check2 fails) then ["check2 failed"] else []
```

Surely there is a more idiomatic way to accumulate changes to `errors` without making a new variable every time. Do I need to break out `Data.IORef` for mutable variables? Seems like overkill.

If I simply remove the apostrophes, the compiler returns an error because it gets caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: Try looking up the _Writer monad_ and the _State monad_. The former is probably best for this particular scenario, but the latter is very widely used and is more generally applicable to other situations.

Comment: There are better approaches to this particular problem that others have pointed out, but a nice trick is to use `do` notation with intensional shadowing, as in http://brandon.si/code/translating-some-stateful-bit-twiddling-to-haskell/ . You can even do this with the instance `Monad` for `((->) a)` rather than Identity if you don't want to import anything. The only downside is ghc doesn't yet offer a finer-than-file-level-grained way to disable warnings for shadowing

Comment: ^^^ [Oleg's post](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-July/109116.html); code: `(do { x <- pure foo; x <- pure $ bar x; return $ baz x }) ()` (with the function monad).

Answer (score 6):

You could group the conditions and messages together

```
checksTodo = [(check1 fails, "check1 failed"), (check2 fails, "check2 failed")]

errors = map snd (filter fst checksTodo)
```

If you are comfortable using the list comprehension syntax, you could instead write it in a more readable fashion:

```
errors = [ msg | (cond, msg) <- checksTodo, cond ]
```

> If I simply remove the apostrophes, the compiler returns an error because it gets caught in an infinite loop.

This is happening because `let` bindings in Haskell (unlike most languages) are recursive by default. Which means that if you say

```
let errors = errors ++ if (check1 fails) then ["check1 failed"] else []
```

the compiler will treat it as a recursive definition. When you try to evaluate `errors` at runtime, you go into an infinite loop as you need `errors` to compute `errors`.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```
let errors = 
       [ "check1 failed" | check1 fails ] ++
       [ "check2 failed" | check2 fails ] ++
       ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What [theindigamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2682729/theindigamer) said, plus, the idiomatic way to do error checking is usually having your checker return an `Either`: if something goes wrong, produce a `Left` with the error message, otherwise a `Right` with the result.

Since, in this case, your checks aren't producing an actual result, you can make the result the unit type `()`; thus, you can convert your checks to generate `Either` like this:

```hs
check1Either = if check1 fails then Left "check1 failed" else Right ()
```

And then, just run the checks and filter the elements with a `Left` using the `lefts` function in `Data.Either`:

```hs
import Data.Either

errors = lefts [check1Either, check2Either]
```

(You might ask, if there isn't going to be a result to fill `Right` with, why not use `Maybe`? You can, and filter errors with `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe`; it's just that `Nothing` is usually interpreted to mean that the computation failed, and `Just` usually means success - the opposite of what happens here - whereas, idiomatically speaking `Left` is usually interpreted as an error)